# Getting a random string back from CSV file once its been formatted

Tags: python-2.7, csv

Been tackling this :

```
def names():
    with open('names.csv') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       for row in reader:
         return [r.lower().strip().replace(" ","") for r in row]
           randName = random.choice(r)
           print randName
```

I am trying to get this function to read a CSV file with around 1000 names , formating by trimming white spaces and commas out also lowercasing the name. Then i wanted to assign randName to random value of the list which the r list brings back. 
There are no errors when i call this but have no results when trying to print out randName. My goal is for this function is to retrieve a random name once all CSV file been formatted and print it out

Where am i going wrong here?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Tweaked the code abit :

```
 import csv
 import random

 def randStrings(csvFile1,csvFile2):
    getNameList = csv.reader(open(csvFile1))
    randName = sum([i for i in getNameList],[])
    getCompanyList = csv.reader(open(csvFile2))
    randCompany = sum([i for i in getCompanyList],[])
    combinedString = random.choice(randName) + "@" + random.choice(randCompany).lower().replace(" ","") +".com"
    return combinedString   

print randStrings('names.csv','companys.csv')
```

Two things i need help with , for the part : random.choice(randCompany).lower().replace(" ","") 
is a way to put multiple replacements? to get rid of . and , plus hidden white spaces in the the words??

Secondly , how can i call the "combinedString" return value out of this function?? i will need to use it in another function.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your function quits at the `return` statement! The next two lines never get executed.